# Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark. When I try to use `distinct()`, I receive some errors.

Here is my code:

```py
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1,1,2,2,3])
>>> rdd.collect() # output:[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

>>> rdd.distinct().collect() # error
```

Here is error message:
[Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tZ2E.png)

```
22/10/18 15:11:56 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/10/18 15:11:56 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/10/18 15:11:56 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) (master executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

22/10/18 15:11:56 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 1: Stage cancelled
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 1 (distinct at <stdin>:1) failed in 4.131 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) (master executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) on master, executor driver: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1
) [duplicate 1]
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
22/10/18 15:11:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: collect at <stdin>:1, took 4.167721 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1197, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) (master executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 668, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 452, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 590, in _create_parametrized_type_hint
    return origin[args]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/typing.py", line 1131, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 113, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
```

Also, when using `reduceByKey()`, I get a similar error. How to figure out this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With the code that you provided, I cannot reproduce the problem. I successfully get `[2, 1, 3]` collected.

Comment: I have solved this problem. It may be that the software version does not match.

Comment: I had the same problem running Spark 3.3.1 with Python 3.6 installed. Reinstalled with Python 3.7 as specified in the requisites and it worked fine.